# When does a passed class instance require an import in python

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

So I have a python 2.7 project with three modules. Two contain classes and one is a script. An example files structure is shown below

```
project/

__main__.py
__init__.py 

- serial_connect/
    ser_conn.py
    __init__.py

- ui/
    parse_file.py
    __init__.py
```

**ser_conn.py** contains a class which handles all interaction with some RS-232 hardware device. It contains methods such as `open(), close(), send_go()` just basically everything required for this connection.

**parse_file.py** contains a class which has methods relating to parsing a file and getting text commands which are associated with serial commands.

e.g. if the text file contains the command "send_go" parse_file.py will parse this command and call `Ser_Conn.send_go()`

**__main.py__** contains the `main()` function. in `main()` an instance of the Ser_Conn class is created and then passed to the Parse_File class as there exists only one instance of a serial connection in the program and it is required by both `main()` and the Parse_File class.

### My question is as follows

In methods of Parse_File I call methods of the Ser_Conn instance, such as `Ser_Conn.send_go()` but parse_file.py does not complain about there being no

```
from serial_connect.ser_conn import Ser_Conn
```

There only exists a ser_conn import in __main__.py. why does this work?

Comment: I presume you're passing the connection object to the parse_file function?

Comment: yes exactly. main creates connection instance, passes it to parse_file. parse_file sets it to a member variable and does work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, an instance carries all the "stuff" that it needs to do it's work along with it.  At a high level, (and somewhat simplified) when you write:

```
qux.whatever
```

python looks at the object `qux` and then finds its `whatever` attribute (if it has one).  Note that python *doesn't care* what type `qux` is, only that it has a `whatever` attribute.  I could create multiple objects that satisfy this interface:

```
class Foo(object):
    whatever = 'Hey Dawg!'

class Bar(object):
    whatever = 'I satisfy the interface too!'
```

Also note that these objects could be defined *anywhere*.  As long as you manage to get a reference to the object (e.g. it was passed into a function) you can use the object with all of it's attributes and methods.

maybe a more concrete example would help -- Say you have 4 modules, `foo`, `bar`, `call_method` and `driver`.  `foo`, `bar` and `call_method` don't know anything about each other, but `driver` imports the other 3.  Then you can do something like this:

```
# foo.py
class Foo(object):
   def method(self):
       return 'foo!'

# bar.py
class Bar(object):
    def method(self):
       return 'bar!'

# call_method.py
def go(object_with_method):
    print(object_with_method.method())

# driver.py
import call_method
import foo
import bar

call_method.go(Foo())  # call the method on a foo instance
call_method.go(Bar())  # call the method on a bar instance
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Me mostly being a "C guy" some of the power and "feature hiding" of python is still a mystery/amazing to me.

Comment: @C.ZachMartin -- Yeah, this can be a bit confusing to people who come from statically typed languages (C, Java, etc.).  Dynamically types just figure out if they can complete what you ask them to at runtime.  There's a performance cost to this freedom (and sometimes it leads to harder to find bugs in particularly big projects), but it's super nice for smaller projects.

Comment: A small addition to your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong but this is a part of why Python is a "Duck Typed" language.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the connection instance to `parse_file` which means Python already knows the class and other details of that object. So that's why you don't need to import the class again in the `parse_file` code.

You only need to import something if you wish to use that something in that file.

When you created the object Python used the class to construct the object and that's sufficient. You can of course add that import line in `parse_file` but only if you actually need to use the class in that file (otherwise the import line it's very useful).

Comment: So in this example I **am** using the connection class in parse_file. I am calling methods such as Ser_Conn.send_go() for example

Comment: Could you include the code for `parse_file`? It could be that you have a variable called `Ser_Conn` which now stores the connection instance.